# How to get local time in another time zone in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, utc

In a Silverlight app, if I know the Timezone Id, how can I get either the current UTC offset for that timezone or the current time?

If I am on the east coast and I want to know the current UTC offset or the current time in Arizona, how can I do this in Silverlight?

This is not available in Silverlight:

```
var AZTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(SomeDatetime, "US Mountain Standard Time");
```

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.UtcNow` also here is a good example of what you could try it also checks `Daylight Savings Time` http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/TimeZoneSample12142005103321AM/TimeZoneSample.aspx

Comment: Apparently the Silverlight TimeZoneInfo only supports two predefined time zones, [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local(v=vs.95).aspx) and [Utc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.utc(v=vs.95).aspx). There is nothing like the [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx) property of the .NET TimeZoneInfo. As far as I understand, it simply can't deal with other time zones.

Comment: You might want to un-accept my answer to let me delete it, it appears to be wrong (I didn't really help you, did I?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I appear to have made a mistake, the answer below is for WPF. I don't know of a way to do what was asked in Silverlight and I can't delete this answer.**

This works for me:

```
TimeZoneInfo GermanTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
var dateTimeInBerlin = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, GermanTimeZone);
```

The time zone names are configured in the windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a service for the Silverlight app that doesn't whatever conversions since the server's .Net code has all that timezone functionality.  Then just have the Silverlight client call that service when conversions are needed.